# AndEngine sprite rotation on ground

Tags: java, android, box2d, andengine, game-engine

He is there a easy way to solve this problem

my sprite rotation is enable , meaning he can spin , 
but when I'm walking on the ground and the sprite land in 90* or 180 * he walk on the side , or on the head

is there a way to set it when in land the ground to spin it in the angle of the ground?

Thanks

Comment: I didnot got exactly what you want.But from my understanding i think you want to spin your sprite to ground angle. Get the rotation angle of your ground and then set that to rotation of your sprite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use onUpdate method of your physicsWorld. You can also use onUpdate of the player or even contactListener. I can't provide more information because you didn't;) 
Then check every frame (thanks onUpdate) what is the ground angle in the place where player stand in the moment (by checking his and ground position). Then you can use rotate method to set Player's rotation equal to ground angle. If you want fluent animation of rotation use 
this: `registerEntityModifier(new RotationModifier(0.3f, 0, 180))` for Player entity